# Why "Custom Script" and "Enable Customizing Master Pages and Page Layouts" are disabled by default inside sharepoint office 365

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, office-365, central-administration, administration

I am working on a new Office 365 SharePoint 2013 online site collection. now when i investigate the admin options i found that these 2 options are disabled inside my Office 365:-

1- "Custom Script"

2- "Enable Customizing Master Pages and Page Layouts"

now i need to enable both options. first option to be able to add script editor web parts to my pages , second option to be able to customize page layouts.

but before enabling these 2 options inside my Office 365, can anyone advice why  these options are disabled by default inside SharePoint online (office 365) while they are enabled by default inside SharePoint 2013 on-premise ? i mean are there any security problems or other limitations i need to be aware of before enabling these 2 options ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is disabled by default, main reason is Security. initially it was allowed but later( in 2015) MSFT disable it via security Fix. I.e

- Uploading files that potentially include scripts, will be blocked
- SharePoint Designer
- Save Site as Template
- Many web parts also blocked.

Check this Office blog for complete information.

[Turn scripting capabilities on or off](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Turn-scripting-capabilities-on-or-off-1F2C515F-5D7E-448A-9FD7-835DA935584F?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

**Note** There is one catch in it, when you enable that feature it will take 24 hours to be enabled. As this Depend on a timer job which run once in 24 hours.

Comment: Yes that's correct, you open the Sharepoint for scripting and others files types for uploading...check the link, for complete list

Comment: Thanks for ur reply, yes i know that i need to wait for 24 hours . but now my question is mainly about the consideration/drawbacks when enabling these features and why they are disabled by default.. So now if i enable these 2 options; "Custom Script" & "Enable Customizing Master Pages and Page Layouts" , does this mean that my SP online will have security holes ???

Comment: so are you saying that i should not enable these options !! now the problem is that many useful features which i need will not be available unless i enable "custom script" , so not sure what i need to do,, should i keep them disabled and lose the useful capabilities OR should i enable them and face the security problem , can you adivce more on this please ?

Comment: I am not saying, don't enable it but I am telling you about the risk. Keep in mind this was enable by default 2 years ago. So just think and proper plan it... so it's depend on your requirements...

Comment: now my requirements that i need to write custom scripts and allow users to rate the discussion board articles and other features,, and those can not be achieved unless custom script is enabled. also i need to be able to modify the page layouts and this can not be achieved unless the "Enable Customizing Master Pages and Page Layouts"  is enabled. so for sure i need them to be enabled,, but not sure if i can get them in a secure way , i mean if i can minimize the security risks they poses when these features are enabled ??

Comment: I am not the one who can tell you enable it or disable...it is purely your decision...but as per my experience and talk with other folks, I noticed this feature is enable on most of their deployments...for one or other reason...as I said earlier This feature was enabled by default for everybody 2 years ago...MSFT just put another layer of security that's it..

Comment: i think at this stage , i do not have any option but to enable it, as seems lot of features will be unavailable when the custom script is disabled..